# DOM not showing images added dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page with lots of images and infinite scroll. So, I want to lose the images when they go out of the viewport and then show them again when scrolled back in.

This is an example image and holding div:

```
<div class="imgHldr2" data-content="<img src=/path/to/my/image.jpg class=wImage>">
  <img src=/path/to/my/image.jpg class=wImage>
</div>
```

When the element with class `imgHldr2` goes out of viewport I hide the image, then rebuild it from the `data-content` contents.

It all works perfectly apart from that when adding the image back into the DOM its not rendering/showing. Here's how I'm doing it:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
  if(timer) {
    window.clearTimeout(timer);
  }

  timer = window.setTimeout(function() {

    $(".imgHldr2:below-the-fold").each(function() {
      $(this).next('.wImage').detach();
    });
    $(".imgHldr2:above-the-top").each(function() {
      $(this).next('.wImage').detach();
    });
    $(".imgHldr2:in-viewport").each(function() {
      // the next line puts the content back in as I can see it in inspector
      // but it doesn't actually redraw it
      $(this).append($(this).data('content'));
    });

  }, 350);
});
```

Comment: don't src's urls need to be in a quotations or double-quotations?

Comment: Why do you `detach` without saving a reference? Either use `remove` or save the detached object somewhere (in holder's data, for example). One more thing, are you sure about using `next`? Or maybe `find` is more appropriate?

Comment: @FilipSpiridonov As I said, it works perfectly, its nothing to do with how I remove from the DOM it's about showing the image again when it's re-introduced. I'm not detaching without saving a reference, the reference is in the image holder's data-content field

Answer (score 0):

Try it with **var** keyword.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
  if(timer) {
    window.clearTimeout(timer);
  }

    var timer = window.setTimeout(function() {

    $(".imgHldr2:below-the-fold").each(function() {
      $(this).next('.wImage').detach();
    });
    $(".imgHldr2:above-the-top").each(function() {
      $(this).next('.wImage').detach();
    });
    $(".imgHldr2:in-viewport").each(function() {
      // the next line puts the content back in as I can see it in inspector
      // but it doesn't actually redraw it
      $(this).append($(this).attr('data-content'));
    });

  }, 350);
});
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gd7cokyy/
(In the fiddle it adds elements, but it does not remove them.)
Explanation why can be found in discussion bellow.

However, lines `if(timer) { window.clearTimeout(timer); }` are unecessary.
Actually, why do you use that timer?

```
$(window).scroll(function() {    
    $(".imgHldr2:below-the-fold").each(function() {
      $(this).next('.wImage').detach();
    });

    $(".imgHldr2:above-the-top").each(function() {
      $(this).next('.wImage').detach();
    });

    $(".imgHldr2:in-viewport").each(function() {
      $(this).append($(this).attr('data-content'));
    });
});
```

You also should use remove() method of jquery instead of detach().

I would also consider changing the structure of your HTML, storing html in attributes is never a good practice. Furthermore, if it is only src of image you want to store, you can store just that value. Your way:

```
<div class="imgHldr2" data-content="<img src=/path/to/my/image.jpg class=wImage>">
  <img src=/path/to/my/image.jpg class=wImage>
</div>
```

Right way:

```
<div class="imgHldr2" data-img-path="/path/to/my/image.jpg">
  <img src="/path/to/my/image.jpg" class="wImage">
</div>
```

Comment: This should not be correct. Using the `var` keyword here will ensure the scope of `timer` is only within the anonymous function executed on scroll. Every time the function executes, it would create a new `timer` and it would never be cleared. In this case, you NEED it to be global, which not using `var` does.

Comment: It is global currently

Comment: In my answer I was trying to point out that with var keyword, it adds elements to container, without it no - that was the behavior. I think that lines if(timer) { window.clearTimeout(timer); } are completely unecessary in this case. Does not setTimeout() works like - create new anonymous function instance (or expression); execute; it and clear function automatically , because it will never be called again. w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp Am I wrong?